# Passing Vector3D struct into pointer-based API

Tags: c++

I'm working with VTK and it's API requires all calls to be invoked either with `double*` or with `double[3]`. So the methods accept a pointer to some point in 3D space.

I've created the `Vector3D` struct, that is the simple aggregate:

```cpp
struct Vector3D
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
```

And now I want to use it for VTK API, because VTK doesnt have `Point3D` / `Vector3D` struct itself and using raw pointers is weird.
So, I've used the following method:

```cpp
double* ptr() noexcept
{
    // I'm not totally sure, maybe it'd be better to use `reinterpret_cast<...>(&x)` here
    return reinterpret_cast<double*>(this);
}
```

And that worked, but now I realized that I need the `const` overload too.

```cpp
const double* ptr() const noexcept
{
    return reinterpret_cast<const double*>(this);
}
```

But I didnt see any cases, where the `reinterpret_cast<const T*>` was used.
And it got me thinking: "Am I doint it right?"

Comment: I dont want to use direct `&` everywhere. So, if we left it a method, you suggest replacing `this` to `&x` and removing `reinterpret_cast`?
Am I right?

Like `return &x` in both methods;

Comment: you can reinterpret cast to get a pointer but the pointer is not pointing to an array of doubles which is what VTK probably expects. Why do you not use an array of doubles?

Comment: just because some api wants you to pass a raw pointer does not mean that you have to use raw pointers anywhere in your code. Use `std::array<double,3> vector3d;` then pass `vector3d.data()` to the function that wants a pointer

Comment: Structs are memory aligned. If you take the address of its first element, especially in your situation where types are all the same, its like a `double[3]` array. So, inside the function, if you return the address of the first element `x`, you will get what you want. `double *ptr() noexcept { return reinterpret_cast<double*>(&this->x); }`

Comment: @nomoresigsegv why cast at all?  `return &x` will be of the correct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. You can add `static_assert(sizeof(Vector3D) == sizeof(double) * 3);` if you want to be extra cautious, but it will probably never fire.

Formally, the behavior is undefined if you try to access any member other than `x` through this pointer, since `+`/`-`/`[i]` (with nonzero offset) can only be used to reach an element of an array through a pointer to a different element, and you don't have an array.

However, in practice, the code using the pointer is likely hidden in a different translation unit (possibly a library), preventing the compiler from noticing the UB and being able to optimize based on that. Even if used in the same translation unit, it's unlikely that a compiler would break such code.